# URL not rewriting correctly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url which is:

```
http://example.com/NEW2014/portfolio/project.html?project_name=test
```

Which I want to be able to rewrite to:

```
http://example.com/NEW2014/portfolio/project/test
```

This is what I'm trying but I get 500 Internal Server error

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/.]*)/?$ /portfolio/project.html?project_name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please see apache error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting 500 internal error because your rule is looping. To fix this have this rule in `/NEW2014/portfolio/.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /NEW2014/portfolio/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^project/(.+?)/?$ project.html?project_name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```